# Можно ли поставить выполнения скрипта cron на паузу/перервать nodejs

Tags: node.js

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть некий скрипт на nodejs для отправки писем, работает через крон т.е. каждую секунду отправляет письмо, подскажите в ноде есть такая возможность так сказать поставить на паузу отправку или во все перервать? Также интересует вопрос, знаю что нод однопоточный язык но,  есть ли возможность запустит в 2-5 потоков отправку писем ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Если процесс node работает непрерывно и отправляет письма по внутреннему расписанию, то можно добавить условия или прервать цикл отправки писем. Многопоточность организовать можно смотри [fork](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/cluster.html) или [worker_threads](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/worker_threads.html)